# Can't fire custom events

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am unable to get custom events working, instead I get an `unrecognized selector`.  This type of code has been working since before but it has recently stopped working:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  Ti.App.fireEvent('clearHistoryTable');
}, 3000);

Ti.App.addEventListener('clearHistoryTable',function(e) {
  alert('a');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question.  For the best possible answers questions should be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have done to get to where you are now.  There is a [great article about how to write good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider having a read of it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: Be sure you didnot remove this `clearHistoryTable ` event anywhere !

Comment: That's not the issue.  It does this on any custom one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work for you, but read this for a more efficient way to handle that type of event...
http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/10/the-case-against-ti-app-fireevent-2/

Comment: I need to be able to use this functionality.

Comment: I was just going based off the sample code you provided.  If you are firing and receiving the event both on the Javascript side, you don't need to use Ti.App.  In fact, as the article I posted discusses, it's less effective to do so because it crosses the Kroll bridge twice and doesn't need to.

Comment: Yea I had to resort to that, but its not ideal and is a big pain in the ass as the app gets bigger.  I just need to call my event to clear a  table and reload it from another window.

Comment: I mean, there is zero reason this simple code shouldn't be working.


var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;


function loadData(){
 alert('a');
}

Ti.App.addEventListener('loadData',function(e){
 loadData();
});
setTimeout(function() {
      Ti.App.fireEvent('loadData');
}, 3000);

Comment: I completely agree with you there.  Copying and pasting this second sample code works fine in my test app (using SDK 5.2.2GA).  And I'm sorry to keep beating the dead horse, but the larger your app gets the greater the reason to avoid Ti.App for events.  Using the Backbone events (dispatcher) the way that Fokke describes definitely works across windows/controllers.